# Is it possible to create controlled gates with an exponent in Cirq?

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, cirq

Is it possible to create controlled gates with an exponent in Cirq? For example, a controlled $\sqrt Z$ gate.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to create controlled gates with an exponent in Cirq.

For the specific case of the Z gate, Cirq includes a dedicated CZ gate that can be raised to a power:

```
cs = cirq.CZ**0.5
```

More generally, `cirq.ControlledGate` works on any gate. It's a bit clunkier than the dedicated gates, but it does support being raised to a power (as long as the gate it is being applied to can be raised to a power). The following two lines are equivalent:

```
controlled_sqrt_y = cirq.ControlledGate(cirq.Y**0.5)
controlled_sqrt_y = cirq.ControlledGate(cirq.Y)**0.5
```

You can also raise to a power after applying to qubits, which is syntactically convenient:

```
cs_on_ab = cirq.CZ(a, b)**0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation and the GitHub, there is a something called `ControlledGate`. This class is said to augment existing gates with a control qubit. 
You can look at the  [test file](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/75bb352554424b1767e9ef4450f1d01492488e90/cirq/ops/controlled_gate_test.py). 
I can see line 72 :

```
cxa = cirq.ControlledGate(cirq.X**cirq.Symbol('a'))
```

Could you try:

`gate = cirq.ControlledGate(cirq.X**0.5)` ?